# How to create a new webpage when user prompts

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to create a website where the user can simply send a message to another friend using my website. I will store the messagfe by encrypting it simply using hashing and then I woyuld like to create a random URL for the webpage where that message can b e seen by the users fiend. I want the page to be random enough that no one runs into it by mistake or purposefully. I want to give the address to the user who would further give it to his known who would access the webpage to recieve message. How to do this ?
I would like to create a new random Url on users prompting and then return it to the user.

Thanks in advance,

Nalin Bhardwaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the message and its md5- or sha1-hash in a MySQL database. Your getMessage.php-website could take a URL-parameter like `?msgID=<hash>` via `GET`. A MySQL-query could then deliver the message associated with that hash to the dynamically built php page.

For a prototype, that is fine. However, you might need some kind of collision avoiding in your hashing function, so that no two messages will result in the same hash value.